# overriding template of password change fos user bundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

HI everyone Im working on a project using FOSUserBundle to manage users inside the application, what I want to do is to - almost the same thing as - move/copy the template of password change inside a page that contains the profile of the current user, it works fine, it displays for me ChangePasswordFormType, however when I submit the changes to the controller it gives me an error like this :

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to    User\UserBundle\Entity\Acces::checkAllFields() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext, instance of Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContext given
```

thats my controller :

```
$request = $this->get('request');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $roles = $em->getRepository('AdminAdminBundle:Role')->findAll();

    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = new \User\UserBundle\Entity\Acces();
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();


    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_INITIALIZE, $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }

    /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
    $formFactory = $this->container->get('fos_user.change_password.form.factory');

    $form = $formFactory->createForm();
    $form->setData($user);

    $currentuser = $user;
    $personnel = $em->getRepository('AdminAdminBundle:Personnel')->findBy(array('acces' => $user));

    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('Cet utilisateur n\'a pas d\'acces à ce contenu.');
        }

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
            $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.change_password.form.factory');

            $form = $formFactory->createForm();
            $form->setData($user);

            $form->handleRequest($request);


            if ($form->isValid()) {
                /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
                $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

                $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS, $event);

                $userManager->updateUser($user);

                if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                    $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('personnel_profile');
                    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
                }

                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
                return $response;
            }
        }
```

The View code is :

```
<form role="form" name="passchange" method="post" {{ form_enctype(password_form) }} action="{{ path('personnel_update_personnal') }}" id="form_sample_2">
     <input type="hidden" name="passchange" value="0" />
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label">Mot de passe actuel</label>
         {{ form_widget(password_form.current_password,{ 'attr': {'required': 'required', 'class':'form-control'} }) }}
         <span class="help-block">                                    
             {{ form_errors(password_form.current_password) }} </span>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label">Nouveau mot de passe</label>
         {{ form_widget(password_form.plainPassword.first,{ 'attr': {'required': 'required', 'class':'form-control'} }) }}
         <span class="help-block">
         {{ form_errors(password_form.plainPassword.first) }} </span>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label">Confirmation mot de passe</label>
         {{ form_widget(password_form.plainPassword.second,{ 'attr': {'required': 'required', 'class':'form-control'} }) }}
         <span class="help-block">
         {{ form_errors(password_form.plainPassword.second) }} </span>
     </div>
     <div class="margin-top-10">
         <button type="submit" class="btn green-haze">Valider le changement</button>        
         <button type="reset" class="btn default reset">Annuler le changement</button>
     </div>
 </form>
```

A simple note: The entity User (of the userBundle) in my case is named Acces

The error given above is generated on the line : $form->handleRequest($request);

Plz if someone has encountered this error, any info could be helpful
Thanks a lot.

Edit : the Use Entity :

```
namespace User\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"checkAllFields"})
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *              @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="username", column=@ORM\Column(nullable=true)),
 *              @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="email", column=@ORM\Column(nullable=true)),
 *              @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="password", column=@ORM\Column(nullable=true)),
 *  })
 */
class Acces extends BaseUser 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Admin\AdminBundle\Entity\Role" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\Null(groups={"Registration"})
     */
    private $role;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param \Admin\AdminBundle\Entity\Role $role
     * @return Acces
     */
    public function setRole(\Admin\AdminBundle\Entity\Role $role = null)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return \Admin\AdminBundle\Entity\Role 
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }


    public function checkAllFields(ExecutionContext $context) {
        if (!(($this->username == null && $this->password == null && $this->email == null && $this->role == null )
                 || ($this->username != null && $this->password != null && $this->email != null && $this->role != null )
                )) {
            $context->validate($this->getRole(), 'Acces', array("Registration"));
        }
    }


    public function __toString() {
        return parent::__toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the UserBundle:Acces code

Comment: The log says that the method checkAllFields should be an instance of Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext instead of  Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContext. Try to change your use statement to `use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext`

Comment: If you check my Acces entity it uses the correct ExecutionContext

Comment: Then on the contrary, can you try to change your use statement to `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContext` ?

Comment: Thanks it worked, but when I changed the password , it hasen't changed  !!!!!

Comment: @krachleur you seem to be fetching and re-assigning the user variable and creating the form type and assigning that user a few times. Clean that up first. You may find it sorts this issue out.

Also, if this your own ChangePasswordController and is the function above only a changePasswordAction? I see this is old so you probably have come right or moved on.